# Equivalence Relation on the set of ordered pairs of positive integers

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Have a homework question, but how can I show that the given relation R is reflexive, symmetric and transitive, so that it is an equivalence relation. Appreciate assistance from anyone.

"Let R be the relation on the set of ordered pairs of positive integers such that ((a,b),(c,d)) are in R if and only if ad=bc. Show that R is an equivalence relation."

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: I think the relation is an equivalence relation?

Comment: Yes.  So what needs to be the case for a relation to be an equivalence relation?

Comment: reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
You're trying to prove that positive rational numbers $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$ iff $ad = bc$.

Comment: Thank you naslundx, I think I can go from here now.